# PaperTrail Versions raising ActiveRecord::IrreversibleOrderError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-admin, paper-trail-gem

I have been using papertrail on a project for about a year with no issues. Right now I'm using it on the latest available version (10.3.1), with `ruby 2.4.9` and `rails 5.1.7`. But recently when I ran `rake db:migrate` the versions table was altered automatically on my schema, removing the rails default id as primary key and adding a bigint field also called id:

```
create_table "versions", id: false, force: :cascade do |t|
  t.bigint "id", null: false
  t.string "item_type", null: false
  t.integer "item_id", null: false
  t.string "event", null: false
  t.string "whodunnit"
  t.text "object"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.text "object_changes"
  t.index ["item_type", "item_id"], name: "index_versions_on_item_type_and_item_id"
end
```

This change made rails start complaining about `ActiveRecord::IrreversibleOrderError`, as no primary key was defined for the versions table. Now I'm wondering, what happened? Does this have something to do with rails 5.1 changing ids to bigint? It makes no sense to me as i've been on the same rails versions (5.1.7) since the start, and this change was made about 4 years ago.

Thanks.

Comment: I ran `User.connection.execute "ALTER TABLE versions ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);"` to fix this, now running `PaperTrail::Version.primary_key` returns `"id"` instead of `nil`, but I still don't understand what happened...

Answer (score -1):

Ok, so I'm still a bit confused, mostly as to why the schema was changed and versions had no primary key. But I think the issue with `ActiveRecord::IrreversibleOrderError` was caused by a bump on `rails_admin` (upgraded from 1.4.3 to 2.0.2). For some reason rails_admin now displays the versions table by default on the left menu, inside a `PaperTrail` group. That combined with the fact that ActiveRecord wasn't being able to order the versions table (as there was no primary key or ordering configured), made ActiveRecord start to raise the `IrreversibleOrderError` exception.

To fix this I added the following line to rails_admin initializer (`config/initializers/rails_admin.rb`):

```
RailsAdmin.config do |config|
  ...
  config.excluded_models = [PaperTrail::Version]
  ...
end
```

I also executed a SQL instruction to add `id` as primary key on versions again (allowing to keep the versions section on rails_admin, even though I removed it):

```
ALTER TABLE versions ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);
```

You could add this to a migration (`execute("SQL GOES HERE")`), but it's kind of weird, cause if you reset your DB and run the migrations from scracth it will complain of the primary key being defined twice on the same table (at least, that was what happened in my experience).

I still don't think this is the final solution, as I don't understand the source of the error, so I won't accept it as the solution for now. If anyone can shed any light, will be greatly appreciated!